# How to remove everything from superview

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7

Rather than individually `removeFromSubview` for each thing I want to remove, I'd like to know if there's something which removes *everything* from the superview.

Answer (score 0):

I am using category method for this

```
@interface UIView (Additions)
- (void)removeAllSubviews
@end

@implementation UIView (Additions)
- (void)removeAllSubviews
{
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews)
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
@end
```

So you can call

```
[self.superview removeAllSubviews];
```

to remove everything from superview.

Comment: You should always use a prefix for category methods

Answer (score 0):

```
for(UIView *view in self.superview.subviews)
{
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Be careful with this though, it can remove Apple built-ins that you don't know are there and thereby change the way the view interacts with the user.

Answer (score 0):

One liner

```
[viewYouWantToRemoveFrom.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```